# Why is this cloud deploy not working properly?

Tags: cdf-format, wolfram-cloud

[This deployment](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/fb2373b8-ef8d-4af1-bb40-07b389b1f284) is supposed to be an animation of a slide and crank but the animation is not showing.

I've already tried to use  SynchronousInitialization -> False and SaveDefinitions -> True

This is the code

```
w2 = .02;
rA[theta2_, r2_] := r2*{Cos[theta2], Sin[theta2]};
rAy[theta2_, r2_] := r2*Sin[theta2];
rAx[theta2_, r2_] := r2*Cos[theta2];
theta3[theta2_, r2_] := 
  If[rAy[theta2, r2] < 0, 
   ArcCos[1/r3*Sqrt[(r3^2 - (r2*Sin[theta2])^2)]], -ArcCos[
     1/r3*Sqrt[(r3^2 - (r2*Sin[theta2])^2)]]];
xB[theta2_, r2_] := r2*Cos[theta2] + Sqrt[(r3^2 - (r2*Sin[theta2])^2)];
rB[theta2_, r2_] := {xB[theta2, r2], 0.0};
rBx[theta2_, r2_] := xB[theta2, r2];
rBy[theta2_, r2_] := 0;
vAx[theta2_, r2_] := -r2*Sin[theta2]* w2;
vAy[theta2_, r2_] := r2*Cos[theta2]* w2;
vA[theta2_, r2_] := Sqrt[vAx[theta2, r2]^2 + vAy[theta2, r2]^2];
rICx[theta2_, r2_] := xB[theta2, r2];
rICy[theta2_, r2_] := xB[theta2, r2]*Tan[theta2];
rCGcoupler[theta2_, r2_] := 
  rB[theta2, r2] + 
   r3/2*{-Cos[theta3[theta2, r2]], Sin[theta3[theta2, r2]]};

(* Find w3 = v / r *)
w3[theta2_, r2_] := vAy[theta2, r2]/(
  rAx[theta2, r2] - rBx[theta2, r2]);

vBx[theta2_, r2_] := 
  vAx[theta2, 
    r2] + ((rAy[theta2, r2] - rBy[theta2, r2]) vAy[theta2, r2])/(
   rAx[theta2, r2] - rBx[theta2, r2]);
aBx[t_, r2_] := D[vBx[(w2*tt), r2], tt] /. tt -> t;
theta2 = 0;
rAO = rA[0, r2];
rBO = rB[0, r2];
Manipulate[
 r3 = factor*r2;
 theta2 = t*w2;
 rAO = rA[theta2, r2];
 rBO = rB[theta2, r2];
 crankVelocity = vA[theta2, r2];
 Grid[{{Graphics[{
      {Dashed, Circle[{0, 0}, r2]},
      {Red, EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}], 
       Rectangle[{rBO[[1]] - .75, rBO[[2]] - 1.5}, {rBO[[1]] + .75, 
         rBO[[2]] + 1.5}]},
      {Thick, Darker[Green], Line[{{0, 0}, rAO, rBO}]},
      {Darker[Blue], Disk[{0, 0}, 0.2], 
       Disk[{rAO[[1]], rAO[[2]]}, 0.2], 
       Disk[{rBO[[1]], rBO[[2]]}, 0.2]}},
     PlotRange -> {{-5, 15}, {-4, 4}}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
     ImageSize -> {500, 200}]}
   }],
 {{r2, 2, "Linea A"}, 1, 3, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{factor, 2.5, "Linea B"}, 2.25, 4, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{t, 0, "Rotacion"}, 0, 200*3.14, 3.14/16, Animator, 
  AnimationRunning -> True, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 TrackedSymbols -> True, SaveDefinitions -> True, 
 SynchronousInitialization -> False]
```

I dont think that is too much to calculate, it runs well enough in the pc.

Comment: One thing: that link hasn't been made `"Public"`, but don't. That'll just cause people to eat up your credits. The fundamental issue is I think that for each `Dynamic` call it needs to contact the server to update. Until WRI solves this primary issue `Dynamic` content in the cloud is painfully slow. Better is to export that as a GIF, e.g. via `CloudDeploy[ExportForm[_Manipulate, "GIF"], ...]`. An example of this is [here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.testing/crank.gif).

Comment: Drop `AnimationRunning` and trigger it manually, it won't be neat but at least it will do something. There is not much hope to get a smooth animation as everything needs to go back an forth to the cloud (modulo caching). p.s. SynchornousInitialization does not matter for Cloud Front End.

Comment: @b3m2a1: I have a `Manipulate[..]` named as `out` and want to use `CloudDeploy[ExportForm[_Manipulate, "GIF"], ...]` but can you write the full form of this? Is it `CloudDeploy[ExportForm[out, "GIF"]]` sufficient to replicate your example above?

Comment: @ b3m2a1: I tried `CloudDeploy[ExportForm[out, "GIF"]]`, it works but it works as an animation. I do not want animation but the user to make a choice from the control. Do you know how to do it? Thanks.